# Obtaining a Google Maps Android v2 API Key

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I know that this is not the correct place to ask this question, but could someone please point out a simple tutorial on how to obtain a Google Maps Android v2 API Key and how to use it to display a map in my application.

Thanks.

Comment: "I know that this is not the correct place to ask this question" -- but I'm going to post it anyways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full instructions are [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Comment: Thanks, I've followed the instructions, but I am getting errors, which I have mentioned in another post.